# Android please call response.close(), where to close it?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close()

It has to do with my interceptor but I don't know where to implement `response.code()`.

My interceptor:

```
class AuthInterceptor() : Interceptor {

@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val originalRequest = chain.request()
    val authenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)
    val initialResponse = chain.proceed(authenticationRequest)
    
        if (initialResponse.code == 401 || initialResponse.code == 403) {
            val responseNewToken = SessionManager.refreshToken?.let {
                RetrofitBuilder.api(ApiService::class.java)
                    .refreshAuthorizationToken(TokenRefreshRequest(it, it, null))
                    .execute()
            }
            if (responseNewToken != null || responseNewToken?.code() == 200) {
                responseNewToken.body()?.let { response ->
                    SessionManager.token = response.token
                    SessionManager.refreshToken = response.refreshToken

                }
            }
        }

    val newAuthenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)
    return chain.proceed(newAuthenticationRequest)
}

private fun request(originalRequest: Request): Request {
    return originalRequest.newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${SessionManager.token}")
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .build()
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

[Interceptors](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/) please read the first paragraph here. it says

> If chain.proceed(request) is being called more than once previous
> response bodies must be closed.

That is exactly what you do :D
So, you need to close it before second chain.proceed() or maybe even before the line below.

```
val newAuthenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)
```

to close it, add;

```
chain.proceed(request).body?.close()
```

should be enough. hope it works.

Comment: When I change it , the if (initialResponse.code == 401 || initialResponse.code == 403)  doesn.'t work. Can't call for .code

Comment: so can you try to close it before second chain.proceed()? or maybe even before "val newAuthenticationRequest = request(originalRequest)"

Comment: Worked now my friend. Thank you very much <3